# Attempting to get signal from checkbox change

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox

The following code sets up a list of checkboxes.

```
QWidget *w = new QWidget(this);
w->setFixedSize(300,200);
QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout;

foreach(QString filt, filters){
    QCheckBox *checkbox = new QCheckBox(filt, this);
    checkbox->setChecked(true);
    vbox->addWidget(checkbox);

    connect(this, SIGNAL(statechanged(int)), this, SLOT(cbstate(int)));

}

w->setLayout(vbox);
w->show();
```

The idea is that when the user checks or unchecks an item, it will emit a signal.

In the header file, I have included the following in the private slots:

```
void cbsate(int state);
```

And in the cpp file, I have declared this:

```
void MainWindow::cbstate(int state){
    if(state == 0){
        //unchecked
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Unchecked", "You have unchecked this box");
    }
    else if (state == 2){
        //checked
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Checked", "You have checked this box");
    }
}
```

I'm now getting an error of

> no 'void MainWindow::cbstate(int)' member function declared in class 'MainWindow'

Any ideas? Am I going about this correctly? Thanks.

Comment: You have an error in the way you connect signal and slots try: connect(checkbox, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(cbstate(int)));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definately sounds as if you have not added the method cbstate to your header file correctly.  If you copy and pasted this from your header file, then you have a typo:

```
void cbsate(int state);
```

should be:

```
void cbstate(int state);
```

Comment: Oops, gutted I made a typo! It's now running without any errors but when I attempt to uncheck a checkbox, I get the following errors: Object::connect: No such signal MainWindow::statechanged(int) in ../Images/mainwindow.cpp:38
Object::connect:  (sender name:   'MainWindow')
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')

Comment: You need to connect the checkbox, not the window, i.e. connect(checkbox, SIGNAL(...), this, SLOT(...));

Comment: Sorted, statechanged is stateChanged! Cheers dunc!

Answer (score 1):

To solve connect issue use:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(cbstate(int)));
```

Note that **stateChanged** is used, not **statechanged**.